# Time Series Target variable taken at much lower sample rate than input features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-engineering

I have a regression problem that involves predicting a patient's blood pressure from a range of vital sign readings including PTT, PPG, and HR. Each of these input features has been taken at the same sample rate so I have the same number of values for each. The problem I have run into is that the blood pressure data which matches with the input data has been taken at a much lower sampling rate. For every 1 blood pressure reading, I have 120,000 input readings.

As I am fairly new to data science I am struggling to know what to search online for methods of how to deal with this problem. I have read a few papers and one method they used was to take attributes before and ahead of the timestamp, as seen below.
[image]

What I don't understand is what they do with this? The way I have interpreted it is that they copy the blood pressure to the positions in the input data before and after the matched timestamp. I have included a screenshot below showing the way I have gone about implementing that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do with predictive models is to start simple, and then increase complexity.

I don't know how blood pressure works exactly, but I can say that some columns have more variability than others, which require a different processing.

Before making predictions with the different columns, you can start by making a decision tree model (or random forest) using the mean value of each column from the 120 000 records in order to see if you already have some patterns.

Then, you can apply some data pre processing by detecting the correlated columns (ex: correlation heat map) : some uncorrelated columns could be remove to improve results and reduce processing time. Then you can use a longer sampling rate (ex: every second) using neural networks predictive models like GRU or LSTM to detect dynamics on your values.

Comment: If you consider the answers somewhat usefull, don't hesitate to upvote them as acknowledgment :)